# Importing mesh .dae file in ros noetic

Tags: rviz, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I am trying to import a mesh(.dae) file into .xacro in (ROS noetic):

```
<geometry>
 <mesh filename="package://ros_robotics/meshes/l_finger.dae"/>
</geometry>
```

but when I want to view model in rviz it gives this error :

```
ERROR 1626525294.722785369: Could not load resource [package://ros_robotics/meshes/l_finger.dae]: Collada: File came out empty. Something is wrong here.
```

I ran the $ rospack ros_robotics and the package is there(I have made alot of models in that package and it works)

.dae files are there too I check them with rosls command, but no matter what I do I cant load the files into rviz
I have tried the file:///$(find ros_robotics)/... , file:///ros_robotics/... , package://ros_robotics/... , package://$(find ros_robotics)/..., just puting $(find ros_robotics)/... and etc

nothing has worked yet :(

I also put the files in urdf directory where the .xacro file is and reference it there in the file and it didnt work either.
Just to mention that I am using the .dae files from [this github repo](https://github.com/FairchildC/ROS-Robotics-By-Example-2nd-Edition/tree/master/Chapter5_code/ros_robotics/meshes).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382704/importing-mesh-.dae-file-in-ros-noetic/) by [SC0d3r](https://answers.ros.org/users/78020/sc0d3r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my problem, the issue was that I was getting the .dae files with wget command and it ruined it somehow
and that error message was not helping either, I thought the issue was that the rviz couldnt find the .dae files.
finally I downloaded the files with curl  and it is working now.

---

Originally posted by [SC0d3r](https://answers.ros.org/users/78020/sc0d3r/) with karma: 26 on 2021-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-18**:
The error is pretty clear though:

> Collada: File came out empty. Something is wrong here.

it doesn't say "files can't be found". It says "I tried to load your file, but after doing so, it appears *empty*".

**Comment by [SC0d3r](https://answers.ros.org/users/78020/sc0d3r/) on 2021-07-18**:
But the files weren't empty and when I googled my question all of the answers were that it cant find your .dae files make sure to do this or that etc ...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-18**:
No, the files weren't empty. But it says "*came out* empty".

That means *after* loading/parsing the file, the result was empty.

So the contents couldn't be interpreted successfully, which resulted in Assimp throwing away whatever the files *did* contain, leaving it with nothing.

Hence: "File came out empty".